# jQuery sortable, data attributes not working on sortretreive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently facing a weird behavior of jQuery sortable. I wonder if anyone of you had the same issue. My required functionality:

**I have two lists of items - sale_available_products and sale_selected_products**

**One of them is full, the other empty. When you drag one element from the full one to the empty a modal dialog must appear requiring you to type in the price and then the availability. These two should be stored on the item as data tags**

All logic works correctly until now, however, for some strange reason the data attributes do not get saved. The javascript correctly updates the **li** element with appended html, but does not correctly add data tags.

Setup:

```
$('#sale_available_products').sortable({
    connectWith: '#sale_selected_products',
    dropOnEmpty: true
}).disableSelection();

$('#sale_selected_products').sortable({
    connectWith: '#sale_available_products',
    dropOnEmpty: true
}).disableSelection();
```

Events:

```
 $('#sale_available_products').on('sortreceive', function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.find('.badge').remove();
    ui.item.data('quantity', '');
    ui.item.data('price', '');
});

$('#sale_selected_products').on('sortreceive', function (event, ui) {

    bootbox.prompt("How many " + ui.item.data('name') + " do you want to make available? (0 = infinite)", function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            ui.item.find('.dd-handle').append('  <span class="badge bg-color-blue txt-color-white">' + result + ' items</span>');
            $(ui.item).data('quantity', result);
        }
    });
    bootbox.prompt("Please type in a price for the item (in " + currency + ")", function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            ui.item.find('.dd-handle').append('  <span class="badge bg-color-green txt-color-white">' + result + ' ' + currency + '</span>');
            $(ui.item).data('price', result);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything fires up correctly. The dialog boxes show up and the script appends the values correctly **to the html** but not to the **data-** attributes. Any idea why?

Note, that I also tried `ui.item.data('quantity', result)` and it was the same problem - no JS errors, just not saved.

I appreciate any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery `.data()` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) you use does **NOT** store data on the HTML nodes. The jQuery object keeps an internal cache, where all that data is stored. Data stored in this way can be retrieved by the same function:

```
$(element).data("some-data", 1);
var someData = $(element).data("some-data"); // <- someData will now equal 1
```

If you want to store the data on the HTML node, ie. data that would appear as for example `<div data-some-data="1">`, you can use [the `.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(element).attr("data-some-data", 1);
// now `data-some-data="1"` is present on the HTML element in the DOM
```

The two methods of storing and retrieving data can be used in much the same manner (or even at the same time, though that's not recommended as it is unnecessarily complex). Your code will work exactly as expected; the data is simply stored internally so it is not made visible on the DOM's `HTMLElement`s; so you need to retrieve it with `.data()` as well.

---

ALSO: Note that when you use `.data` to retrieve a data item for an element, the internal cache is queried first; if nothing is found there, the HTML element's `data-` attributes are also checked. Thus when you have `<div data-some-data="1">`, you can use `.data("some-data")` on it to retrieve the `data-` attribute without having explicitly set it via an earlier `.data()` call.

Comment: Thank you. You've made me understand the working of jQuery's data function. I was quite sure that it always appended the HTML attribute with the tags and used it to retreive the values for future calls. This explains why data('quantity') returned a digit even though it was not visible in the DOM. 

Thank you, I can move forward now :)

Answer (score 0):

Events:
Instead of  `$(ui.item).data('quantity', result)` use this `$(result).data('quantity')`

```
 $('#sale_available_products').on('sortreceive', function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.find('.badge').remove();
    ui.item.data('quantity', '');
    ui.item.data('price', '');
});

$('#sale_selected_products').on('sortreceive', function (event, ui) {

    bootbox.prompt("How many " + ui.item.data('name') + " do you want to make available? (0 = infinite)", function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            ui.item.find('.dd-handle').append('  <span class="badge bg-color-blue txt-color-white">' + result + ' items</span>');
        }
        return $(result).data('quantity');
    });
    bootbox.prompt("Please type in a price for the item (in " + currency + ")", function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            ui.item.find('.dd-handle').append('  <span class="badge bg-color-green txt-color-white">' + result + ' ' + currency + '</span>');
        }
       return $(result).data('price');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time explaining this. The result object comes from another plugin, please disregard this.

It's the ui.item that I want to attach my data tags to.